# UItabelview reference to curent anchored header section

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have implemented custom header sections for my UItableView and it its all working like a charm. However as a section gets anchored to the top of the list i would like to change the height of it.

I have thus far not had any luck figuring out hot to get a reference to the current anchored header section.

help much appreciated

Cheers

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: sure thing. I create the sections from a custom view in viewForHeaderInSection and set the height of 60 in heightForHeaderInsection. here i am getting the desired resultat. but what i really want to do is that once a header gets anchored to the top of the tableveiew (during scroll) i would like to shrink that header to say a height of 40. but only while being anchored.  once its not the top anchored header it would go back to 60.

Comment: alright i think I know how to solve your issue give me some time to test it and get back to you :)